# Deal with CROSS APPLY in stored procedure when using a JSON to load data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables to populate using a SP in SQL Server. In my case, I'm passing a JSON array as data input and then populate data. In these 2 tables all the primary keys are auto generated.

When I generate the `PARENT` table, I need to use that newly created `ID`s as foreign keys in `PRODUCT` table for each record. I'm able to do this with below SP, but when I use `CROSS APPLY` it duplicates the records as size of the array.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CREATE_PRODUCT]
    @parentJSONData NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SAVE TRANSACTION StartPoint;
    DECLARE @PARENT TABLE ([ID] INT, [PARENT_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK] INT, [EFFECTIVE_TO_WEEK] INT, [ADD_FLAG] INT, [DEL_FLAG] INT)
    DECLARE @PRODUCT TABLE ([PRODUCT_CODE_ID] INT, [PRODUCT_STATUS_ID] INT, [PRODUCT_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [PARENT_ID] INT NOT NULL)
    DECLARE @Output TABLE ([ID] INT,[PARENT_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK] INT)

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage  nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @ErrorState    nvarchar(MAX)
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO PARENT 
        ([PARENT_NAME], [EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK], [EFFECTIVE_TO_WEEK], [ADD_FLAG], [DEL_FLAG]) OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.PARENT_NAME, inserted.EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK INTO @Output
SELECT [PARENT_NAME], [EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK], [EFFECTIVE_TO_WEEK], [ADD_FLAG], [DEL_FLAG]
FROM OPENJSON(@parentJSONData)  WITH (
    PARENT_NAME      NVARCHAR(50) '$.parent.parentName'
        , EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK INT '$.parent.effectiveFromWeek'
        , EFFECTIVE_TO_WEEK   INT '$.parent.effectiveToWeek'
        , ADD_FLAG        INT '$.parent.addFlag.id'
        , DEL_FLAG        INT '$.parent.delFlag.id'
    ) AS jsonValues;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT
([PRODUCT_CODE_ID], [PRODUCT_STATUS_ID], [PRODUCT_NAME], [PARENT_ID])
SELECT PRODUCT_CODE_ID, PRODUCT_STATUS_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@parentJSONData) WITH (
    PRODUCT_CODE_ID      NVARCHAR(50) '$.productCodeID'
        , PRODUCT_STATUS_ID INT '$.productStatusID'
        , PRODUCT_NAME   NVARCHAR(50) '$.productName'
    ) AS jsonValues CROSS APPLY @Output;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
END;
GO
```

JSON

```
[{"parent":{"parentName":"Paper Pack","effectiveFromWeek":202423,"effectiveToWeek":202534,"addFlag":{"id":1,"state":"4x4"},"delFlag":{"id":1,"state":"4x4"}},"productCodeID":23386,"productStatusID":71013,"productName":"Paper Package"},{"parent":{"parentName":"Pen Pack","effectiveFromWeek":202423,"effectiveToWeek":202534,"addFlag":{"id":1,"state":"100"},"delFlag":{"id":1,"state":"100"}},"productCodeID":23387,"productStatusID":71023,"productName":"Pen Box"}]
```

Any way to add the record only once in `PRODUCT` table when doing cross apply? Otherwise, if there is a way to do this without using a CROSS APPLY, please suggest.

Comment: you should join your @t-table against the JSON values somehow, so you get the rows matched against each other, and not just a cross join. surely there's some sort of key column which can be used for that

Comment: Why are doing a `cross apply` to `@output` instead of a join to the `parent` table or a join to `@output`?  Cross apply does exactly what you are experiencing, if there are 3 records in `@output` then every it would apply those 3 parents to every child, which would result in duplicates in the `product` table.

Comment: I tried with both `INNER`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins. But it is same.

Comment: So, what are you joining on?

Comment: I'm joining with `@Output` table to get the last generated IDs.

Comment: If the `parentName` would always be unique across every record in the JSON, you should be able to join using it. If it isn't unique, then you'll probably have to loop through each JSON record to build the parent/child inserts one at a time (which might be easier in the application layer than in T-SQL).  If it is unique, then you could replace the last line in the `Product` insert to something like this: `, PARENT_NAME      NVARCHAR(50) '$.parent.parentName' ) AS jsonValues inner join @Output o on jsonValues.PARENT_NAME = o.PARENT_NAME;`

Comment: Side note: your error handling is a bad idea. To reraise an error you should just use `THROW;` But instead of trying to rollback and reraise yourself, just do `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top and the server will do it for you. Also no need for `SAVE TRANSACTION`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will change it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution to your issue:

```sql
INSERT INTO PRODUCT
([PRODUCT_CODE_ID], [PRODUCT_STATUS_ID], [PRODUCT_NAME], [PARENT_ID])
SELECT PRODUCT_CODE_ID, PRODUCT_STATUS_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@parentJSONData) WITH (
    PRODUCT_CODE_ID      NVARCHAR(50) '$.productCodeID'
        , PRODUCT_STATUS_ID INT '$.productStatusID'
        , PRODUCT_NAME   NVARCHAR(50) '$.productName'
        , PARENT_NAME      NVARCHAR(50) '$.parent.parentName' -- NEW!
        , EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK INT '$.parent.effectiveFromWeek'  -- NEW!
    ) AS jsonValues
INNER JOIN @Output o 
    ON  o.EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK = jsonValues.EFFECTIVE_FROM_WEEK -- NEW!
    AND o.PARENT_NAME = jsonValues.PARENT_NAME -- NEW!
```

I added some columns to join on between the parent and output table. If those aren't enough, you can add more until you get some sort of unique 1 on 1 thing going.

Comment: This works. Issue was I didn't know that I can use this JSON values in this way. Thank you for your help. Learned new things :)

Comment: Great! OPENJSON is like a virtual table so it can be used the same way a regular table would